# OpenWrt install mysql-server

Tags: mysql, openwrt

I am trying to install mysql-server on OpenWrt.

mysql_install_db --force gives me error:

> /usr/bin/my_print_defaults: can't load library 'libnsl.so.0'
>
> FATAL ERROR: Could not find /usr/lib/mysqld
>
> If you compiled from source, you need to run 'make install' to copy
>   the software into the correct location ready for operation.
>
> If you are using a binary release, you must either be at the top level
>   of the extracted archive, or pass the --basedir option pointing to
>   that location.

I have install Libc but I can' find libnsl.so.0 under /usr/lib

I have my.cnf under /etc/

Content of my.cnf:

```
root@OpenWrt:/etc# cat my.cnf
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld.sock

[mysqld]
user        = root
socket      = /var/run/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr

############ Don't put this on the NAND #############
# Figure out where you are going to put the databases
# And run mysql_install_db --force
datadir     = /mnt/data/mysql/

######### This should also not go on the NAND #######
tmpdir      = /mnt/data/tmp/

skip-external-locking

bind-address        = 127.0.0.1

# Fine Tuning
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8

# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes

# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
#expire_logs_days   = 10
#max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name


[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M
```

I also created mkdir /usr/lib/mysqld folder.

```
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Mar 19 17:39 mysqld
```

Then I get error:

```
/usr/bin/my_print_defaults: can't load library 'libnsl.so.0'
Installing MySQL system tables...
/usr/bin/mysql_install_db: line 418: /usr/lib/mysqld: Permission denied

Installation of system tables failed!  Examine the logs in
/var for more information.

You can try to start the mysqld daemon with:

    shell> /usr/lib/mysqld --skip-grant &

and use the command line tool /usr/bin/mysql
to connect to the mysql database and look at the grant tables:

    shell> /usr/bin/mysql -u root mysql
    mysql> show tables

Try 'mysqld --help' if you have problems with paths.  Using --log
gives you a log in /var that may be helpful.

Please consult the MySQL manual section
'Problems running mysql_install_db', and the manual section that
describes problems on your OS.  Another information source are the
MySQL email archives available at http://lists.mysql.com/.

Please check all of the above before mailing us!  And remember, if
you do mail us, you MUST use the /usr/bin/mysqlbug script!
```

I also tried:
cd /usr/lib
wget http://trac.augsburg.freifunk.net/export/3/trunk/freifunk-openwrt-kit-1.6.20-de/root/lib/libnsl.so.0 libnsl.so.0

Then I get error:

```
'/usr/lib/libnsl.so.0' is not an ELF file
```

I do not know what to do any more.
Please give me some idea! Thanks!

UPDATE:
I have updated opkg.conf
Removed mysql-server
And istall mysql-server from new url provided in opkg.conf

mysql_install_db works now great.
I can start mysqld without error BUT

I CANT CHANGE ROOT PASSWORD

```
/usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'xxxxxxxxx'
/usr/bin/mysqladmin: can't load library 'libnsl.so.0'
```

any other option to change mysql root password?

UPDATE2:

Install: http://downloads.openwrt.org/attitude_adjustment/12.09/ar71xx/generic/packages/libmysqlclient_5.1.53-7_ar71xx.ipk

WORKS!!!!

Comment: Hello! could you please elaborate your solution? i have the same problem but didnt understand how you solved.. please elaborate it so i can install it from scratch and qill send you a Bounty for that.. :)

Comment: it was a long time I did this. lucky for you I have broken router I need to repair. Will tell you results in few days. Sorry didn't see your post before today.

Comment: what I remember... sorry if I am not correct try this:

1. ssh to router
2. wget <url>
3. opkg install /path/file.ipk

Comment: What will be the usage? Is there non-flash storage?